# Can't convert character to numeric in R

Tags: r, types, casting

I'm trying to convert values from character to numeric, but R introduces NAs. I have examined one of the problematic values:

```
> x
[1] "11 914 711.5"
> length(x)
[1] 1
> typeof(x)
[1] "character"
> as.numeric(x)
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `scan(text = x, what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE)`

Comment: this is what I get  `> scan(text = x, what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE)
Error in scan(text = x, what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE) : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '11В 914В 711.5'`

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting that error.  `scan(text = x, what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE)#
[1]  11.0 914.0 711.5`   The `x <- "11 914 711.5"`

Answer (score 3):

You could first split your string and then convert them to numeric:

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ' ')))
[1]  11.0 914.0 711.5
```

Comment: I think that the is that R assumes this as a character with length 1, so it can't split it. This is what I get: > as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ' ')))
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: @MimiLazarova you need to split by whitespaces (i.e `' '`)! If you split by `''`, you are actually not splitting

Comment: This is just the formatting, I am splitting by white spaces. I think that R thinks the whole thing as a character and it doesn't recognize the whites paces or anything else.

Comment: @Mimi in R a string is always a character vector of length 1, can you include dput(x) to your question ? You might be confused by the function `length`, expecting it to behave like `nchar`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want. The previous answers and comments assumes you have several numbers in 'x'. Another interpretation gives this solution:

as.numeric(gsub(" ","",x))

Comment: I just want to convert the number to numeric, however R has a different idea about that. x is a character of length 1, not a string, this is where the problem is - it introduces NAs whenever I try to use strings functions on it.

Comment: No, length(x) tells you the length of vector x. In your case it is 1 because you have one character value. So the question is: What is the answer you would like to obtain? 11914711.5 or the three values 11.0, 914.0, 711.5?