# How can you convert a class "character" to class "numeric" in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am running the following code to summarize by INV_ITEM_ID column.

```
temptable <- temptable[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = INV_ITEM_ID,
                         .SDcols = c("Ext Sale", "Ext Total Cost", "CE100", 
                          "CE110","CE120","QTY_SOLD","PACKSLIP_WHSL")]
```

The problem is that INV_ITEM_ID IS character type.  I am needing to convert it to numeric type so that it will properly summarize the data.

How can I go about doing this.  Currently it summarizes but does not leave distinct values.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't convert character to numeric in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294602/cant-convert-character-to-numeric-in-r)

Comment: The `by=` column should show distinct values when given a column of class character... without a concrete example, I guess it is very hard to figure out from our end.

Comment: Yes, the they by is character but when I run the script it spits out 5,135,153 rows with 933,049 distinct values.  I was thinking if I switched it to numeric it would solve the issue.  I don't think that is the solution now though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a spin on the question answered here:
[Converting a factor to numeric without losing information R (as.numeric() doesn't seem to work)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611810/converting-a-factor-to-numeric-without-losing-information-r-as-numeric-doesn)

Can you wrap `INV_ITEM_ID` with these calls: `as.numeric(as.character(INV_ITEM_ID))`?

Comment: When wraping it by as.numeric(as.character(INV_ITEM_ID)) it does not leave distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself with `Reshape2`. First, make sure the variable really is a character:

```
is.character(your_data$INV_ITEM_ID)
```

This should return `TRUE`

If so, then:

```
your_data$INV_ITEM_ID <- as.numeric(your_data$INV_ITEM_ID)
```

I had issues with `sapply()` showing the value as one data type, but it tested as another when I tested with `is.numeric()`

Comment: Using that does allow me to run the script, however it adds the column but is blank.

Comment: When you ran `is.character()`, did it return `TRUE`?

Comment: Yes, it did return as true

Comment: To make it more simple I ran the data with just one other column.  I used the following code.
      temptable <- temptable[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = INV_ITEM_ID,
                             .SDcols = c("Ext Sale")]
I kept INV_ITEM_ID as character type and it still returned 5 million rows and not all distinct

Comment: Sounds like a string issue. Have you tried to `trim()`? Maybe their are white spaces. Also try: `sum(!duplicated(df$column_name))` to count the number of distinct in the column.

Comment: I come up  with the following 

    > sum(!duplicated(mastertable$INV_ITEM_ID))
     [1] 94397
which is way less than 5 millions rows.

What does the trim function do exactly?  How would I go about adding that in my script?

Comment: Also is  there a way of finding out if any have leading white spaces?

Comment: I have tried using the trim function and no luck in summarizing the data with leaving only distinct values