# How do I convert a column from character to double in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to group a dataset on a certain value and then sum a column based on this grouped value.

```
UN.surface.area.share <- left_join(countries, UN.surface.area, by = 'country') %>% drop_na() %>%
rename('surface.area' = 'Surface.area..km2.') %>%  group_by(region) %>% summarise(total.area = sum(surface.area))
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `total.area`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
i Input `total.area` is `sum(surface.area)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: region = "Africa".
```

I think the problem is that the 'surface.area' column is of the character type and therefore the sum function doesn't work. I tried adding *%>% as.numeric('surface.area')* to the previous code:

```
UN.surface.area.share <- left_join(countries, UN.surface.area, by = 'country') %>% drop_na() %>%
rename('surface.area' = 'Surface.area..km2.') %>% as.numeric('surface.area') %>%  group_by(region) %>% summarise(total.area = sum(surface.area))
```

But this gives the following error:

```
Error in group_by(., region) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I think this problem can be solved by changing the 'surface.area' column to a numeric datatype but I am not sure how to do this. I checked the column and it only consists of numbers.

Comment: Can you give a few examples of the numbers in `'surface.area'`?

Comment: Instead of `rename('surface.area' = 'Surface.area..km2.') %>% as.numeric('surface.area')`, try: `rename('surface.area' = as.numeric('Surface.area..km2.')`

Comment: All entries consist of 1 to 6 integers

Comment: When I try rename('surface.area' = as.numeric('Surface.area..km2.') it gives the error Error: Selections can't have missing values. I double-checked and there are really no values other than numbers in the column.

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible example of the dataset

Comment: Please consider this and create a good example of your data so other can support you in finding answer easily.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What happens when you do `as.numeric(UN.surface.area$surface.area)` (assuming this is the starting vector)? If they really are just integers, I can't see why as.numeric could give an error. Perhaps you would find this answers useful (in case there are spaces in your characters): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294602/cant-convert-character-to-numeric-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `dplyr::mutate()`

So instead of:

... `%>% as.numeric('surface.area') %>%`...

do:

...`%>% mutate(surface.area = as.numeric(surface.area)) %>%`...

`mutate()` changes one or more variables within a dataframe. When you pipe to `is.numeric`, as you're currently doing, you're effectively asking R to run

`as.numeric(data.frame.you.piped.in, 'surface.area')`

`as.numeric` then tries to convert the data frame into a number, which it can't do since the data frame is a list object. Hence your error. It's also running with two arguments, which will cause a crash regardless of the structure of the first argument.